# How to read/get extended class static properties using the object iteration

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

In below code - MicroserviceError class extending BaseError class. When I iterate MicroserviceError using the *"Object entries"* method I'm getting only MicroserviceError class static properties. is there any methods or way to to get extended class static properties? Link [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMCiAnFB7F0DeAoaB0ADhgC4LDkAm0KCYV6AdiAJ7QD6TYAtggFzQIpFAEsmAcwDc%20QiXTlKCGnQbM2nYOioDoTAK48ARghQzCxMhWq16jFuw46IwMUVKjmg4WMnnCsgRE%20kYgosBCpGAeEar2GgAisBxIAEqpAPKp0AC8eggA7nCIqBgoABSBFtAArAAMDQA0VRYABknQWkxM1p5M0KZlrc3VhK0Z%20lgQpgBu4QgwYHR6CtBgoQjQpOi2YMAAFtBU0euIrVUAlDJV8oo2XT76lJjlWjqCBsamjXq8uj7iCQ-KiiFxuDxeSK%20CQXHAtQikfaggB0XD%20uV%20fH8o0RKI4b02eQJ2OquIgqOcrlE7j6GJBYOpEKYJIAvrgbiEwhEJAhSJiEOULt4RIC4aMCHRSJN%20mTUdwsVU2RzQuFoDy%20QTBR9DCYsHhxbYpSgZUjyfjtAhWeyLMEVdzeUcFlSacwtVDRfrxZLpVtTRSneC%20la2aBIDAALLhDDTFBzYDINCYAYAD3ITCoMHg01KSc9QU5quE0VVcXU7AAqgA5ADSGQA6pWUukshiekUswmypUDQAWBp1EbigBE5aYAGt0AV%20oMk%20JoDwo%20gY3GEEPB6Mh3XNvswDNNhQmOh9ExyHQaMeJ1OBomsHP54vl-MfkQQPRplsUOwwBIwOJkdAAEkADNLHQDYeGIUwIFBUgYBfN9Ni6KJKCEfQiCITA%20QKUREU6TA6HAJloFEKhkSHS5rgNW0uUiYtYjsMtoCQAANAAFVIkAAZU4jhOLSAA1NIOFSKsm0ybI8jbYpsxvbsDUIPs6gARnXeSR24Ewth2FBjxTEgFhgZdTDXeENy3aAdz3AZgEPY9T2UaAL0nacb2I-odO6UUOM4gAVIRZnmRzoMkPS6CgfzY2M0zoCuXAlQePkZxQABhfYKDHUwMUFXIAD4xWqV9EpvAAZGDoH4MAmHYPIAG0AF0SQIDIjAAK2sZEEBPMQFnKSNXCXAL4xzFALmRIDMCQPZ9nKMCWpyPK83FJLSuEZFgggabZti0YWQuKoHnQV9kRAdAJHKZaYNipUktS9LTEFGQgA)

```
    class BaseError {
    protected readonly _name: string;
    protected readonly _code: number;
    protected readonly _description: string;
    
    public static readonly DB_ERROR = new BaseError(
        5000,
        `DB connection error`,
        `Our services are not able to reach database`
    );

    protected constructor(code: number, name: string, discription: string) {
        this._name = name;
        this._code = code;
        this._description = discription;
    }
}
class MicroserviceError extends BaseError {
    public static readonly UNKOWN_ERROR = new BaseError(
        4000,
        "Unkown error in microservice",
        "We have ecnountered unkown error in  microservice, please try again. If problem persists please contact support with correlation id."
    );

        public static readonly EXPRESS_SERVER_RUN_ERROR = new BaseError(
            4001,
            "Unabe to run express server",
            "We have ecnountered unkown error in running REST service using express server"
        );
}

const errorChecker = () => {
      let errorList :any = [];
      Object.entries(MicroserviceError).forEach(obj=> {
          errorList.push(obj);
      })
    console.log(errorList);
}

errorChecker();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to walk the prototype chain to keep grabbing static properties.

```js
const errorChecker = () => {
      let errorList :any = [];
      Object.entries(MicroserviceError).forEach(obj=> {
          errorList.push(obj);
      })

    Object.entries(BaseError).forEach(obj=> {
          errorList.push(obj);
      })

    console.log(errorList);
}
```

You can get more dynamic if you want by inspecting the "prototype" aka the base class at runtime:

```
const errorChecker = () => {
      let errorList :any = [];

      // start with the "child class"
      let currentClass = MicroserviceError;

      while (currentClass) {
          Object.entries(currentClass).forEach(obj=> {
                errorList.push(obj);
            })

            // get the "base class"
            currentClass = Object.getPrototypeOf(currentClass);
      }

    console.log(errorList);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMCiAnFB7F0DeAoaB0ADhgC4LDkAm0KCYV6AdiAJ7QD6TYAtggFzQIpFAEsmAcwDc+QiXTlKCGnQbM2nYOioDoTAK48ARghQzCxMhWq16jFuw46IwMUVKjmg4WMnnCsgRE+kYgosBCpGAeEar2GgAisBxIAEqpAPKp0AC8eggA7nCIqBgoABSBFtAArAAMDQA0VRYABknQWkxM1p5M0KZlrc3VhK0Z+lgQpgBu4QgwYHR6CtBgoQjQpOi2YMAAFtBU0euIrVUAlDJV8oo2XT76lJjlWjqCBsamjXq8uj7iCQ-KiiFxuDxeSK+CQXHAtQikfaggB0XD+uV+fH8o0RKI4b02eQJ2OquIgqOcrlE7j6GJBYOpEKYJIAvrgbiEwhEJAhSJiEOULt4RIC4aMCHRSJN+mTUdwsVU2RzQuFoDy+QTBR9DCYsHhxbYpSgZUjyfjtAhWeyLMEVdzeUcFlSacwtVDRfrxZLpVtTRSneC+la2aBIDAALLhDDTFBzYDINCYAYAD3ITCoMHg01KSc9QU5quE0VVcXU7AAqgA5ADSGQA6pWUukshiekUswmypUDQAWBp1EbigBE5aYAGt0AV+oMk+JoDwo+gY3GEEPB6Mh3XNvswDNNhQmOh9ExyHQaMeJ1OBomsHP54vl-MfkQQPRplsUOwwBIwOJkdAAEkADNLHQDYeGIUwIFBUgYBfN9Ni6KJKCEfQiCITA+QKUREU6TA6HAJloFEKhkSHS5rgNW0uUiYtYjsMtoCQAANAAFVIkAAZU4jhOLSAA1NIOFSKsm0ybI8jbYpsxvbsDUIPs6gARnXeSR24Ewth2FBjxTEgFhgZdTDXeENy3aAdz3AZgEPY9T2UaAL0nacb2I-odO6UUOM4gAVIRZnmRzoMkPS6CgfzY2M0zoCuXAlVwB4+RnFAAGF9goMdTAxQVcgAPjFapXySm8ABkYOgfgwCYdg8gAbQAXUowqHWASY6BPFLwHCvJI1cJcAvjHMzGtaoCiRV9oFeNqEA6rqIFhPNxQyIwACtrGRGaRQWKa0E2zqwwuZEgMwJA9n2cowJWnJ8sW+TCGSsrhGRYIIHOy7YruggWQuEa7ta3bZrDDFlrWyhkXVViyAUVgiAQDIgJ29rSH2qAPuqJULAedBX2REB0AkcoHpg2KlWStKMtMQUZCAA)